# How to change the data source of a ComboBox?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, combobox

I have two comboboxes. The data sorce of combobox1 is a list of string that is fixed. Combobox2's data sorce will be a list of string that depends on the selection of combobox1. This is very similar to a common case as follows: first enter your contry, then depending on your enter, the second combobox will show you the list of universities in the country.

```
'Change selection of first combobox
Private Sub cbxClient_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cbxClient.SelectedIndexChanged
  Try
    If cbxClient.SelectedIndex <> -1 Then
      GetAccount()
    End If
  Catch
    Throw
  End Try
End Sub

'Based on selection of first combobox, update the data sorce of second combobox
Private Sub GetAccount()
  Try
    m_listAccount.Clear()

    Dim strClient As String = cbxClient.SelectedItem.ToString

    For i As Integer = 0 To m_listDS.Count - 1
      If m_listDS(i).Client.Tostring = strClient Then
        m_ds = m_listDS(i)
        Exit For
      End If
    Next

    If Not m_ds Is Nothing Then
      For Each row As DataRow In m_ds.Tables("Account").Rows
        m_listAccount.Add(row("account").ToString)
      Next
    End If

    cbxAccount.DataSource = m_listAccount

  Catch ex As Exception
  End Try
End Sub
```

My problem is that though m_listAccount updates (has the correct information), the choices shown in cbxAccount are not updated according to m_listAccount (has the wrong information). I do not understand why this happens.

Note: Assume that old string in m_listAccount is {"old1"} (the list only has 1 string) and after updating, the string in m_listAccount is {"new"}. Through break points, I get the following:

```
cbxAccount.DataSorce={"new"}
cbxAccount.SelectedItem={"old1"}
```

In the form, cbxAccount shows "old1" string.

Comment: Is this winforms or asp.net?  If asp.net you need to `.DataBind()` to your datasource.

Comment: Assuming WinForms, it's not very clear where the problem is.  I would avoid swallowing any exceptions though.  How are you verifying the contents of m_listAccount?

Comment: @LarsTech I put a break point to check the value of m_listAccount. I set the debugger to show all exceptions and no exception is thrown in my code. Please see my added note for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
cbxAccount.DataSource = Nothing
cbxAccount.DataSource = m_listAccount
```

If you are just updating the same list object, the datasource might not automatically update, but should if the pointer changes to the datasource.

Or you could try, 
     m_listAccount.AcceptChanges()

If `m_listAccount` is a `DataTable`

Comment: I add cbxAccount.DataSource=nothing and it works well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't look like you're actually calling the databind method, i.e.

```
cbxAccount.DataBind()
```

Try putting that just after you set the data source.

Comment: I don't think the Winforms `ComboBox` has a `DataBind` method. You might be thinking of the ASP ComboBox.

Comment: `DataBind()` is only available for web forms not winforms.  Just an FYI, see my comment in the question asking the OP.

Comment: Yep, sorry, was thinking of the ASP ComboBox. Bugger.